# VS2015 Solution - absolute paths in WebApplication

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, solution

I have created a ASP.NET Web Application with VS2015

Without configuring this explicitly or to my knowledge, the solution seems to use absolute paths for my Trunk.
Now that I want to work with that solution on a different PC it doesn't load correctly. 
Changing the path manually in the .sln file works

Can someone tell me what and where this went wrong?

Comment: "it throws another error" - what error?

Comment: I edited that part. There was an error with "Web.Conf" couldnt be loaded, but the PC was missing some Windows feature.  The issue with the absolute path in the SLN file still persists. Sorry for the mixup